# HTML 5 Video Problem

Tags: html, html5-video, mpeg-4

I'm trying to set up my site to use HTML 5 videos. The mp4 files are served from S3. I've got the MIME type right, and the URL is right. It's not working though. The only thing I can think of is the codec being wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="{url}"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Now as I understand it, the audio codec is always the same. mp4a.40.2. The video is encoded as baseline, but according to http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters#MPEG-4, the last two characters of the video codec, in my code `1E` are variable.

Is having the wrong characters enough to cause the video to not work? If so, how do I find the right settings?

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this stuff. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the video codecs information is that your browser won't download the video if it can't play it. ([found that here](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)) So I think even with a wrong, but common, avc level (last 2 chars) it should download and play. 
I found [this guide](http://www.ode2.com/?p=12) how to determine and change your avc level using a hex editor. [Megui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) apparently also works for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `type` attribute. If that makes it work, you've found the problem. Also, check the actual `Content-Type` HTTP header.