# Which codecs do I need to play this video on my homework page?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have this little video from our English textbook dvd. I want to use it as homework on my webpage. With the settings I normally use, I can only hear it, not see it.

In the attached pic you can see the details of this short video. It mentions

> video codec: MPEG-4 Video (Simple Profile)

and

> audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC

How do I get the video to play? Maybe convert it to something else?

My usual settings are:

```html
<video controls style="width:640px;height:360px;" >
  <source src="video/1 The Mag.mp4"
          type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
```

For other .mp4 this has worked fine, but this is a new book.

[image: from screenshot]

Comment: just remove the type attribute, no need that type attribute in html5. And may be this video is corrupted. Have you checked this video in your computer's installed media player?

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283207/11094356

Comment: Remove the type as @Pragya Sriharsh suggested and change `src="video/1 The Mag.mp4` to `src="video/1%20The%20Mag.mp4`. Urls cannot have spaces so replace any spaces with `%20`.

Comment: @zer00ne yes spaces are also not allowed in URLs.But no need to manually added %20. It added automatically.

Comment: I got rid of the spaces in the name completely, but I still only hear it. I can't see it! Something weird or new about this video. I just tried BCLearnenglish_epi3.mp4, it plays fine in the same webpage.

Comment: I just tried to open the file just using Firefox. I only plays audio, says it is an audio file. However, I can open it ok in my video player. Wrong codec? Need to convert?

Comment: And yes, this video plays fine in my laptop using Ubuntu

Comment: Solved it! I loaded the video in handbrake, converted to .m4v now it works great!